# Why can't I delete files? They can only be deleted permanently

Tags: windows-server-2012, recycle-bin

A user has a seemingly very weird problem, but I noticed something that indicates it isn't what I initially thought it was. Most of my users are not experiencing this problem, even though they are all using the same computer using Remote Desktop Services.

The computer is running Windows Server 2012, keeping up to date regularly. The user in question is a standard user in Active Directory, and everything was working fine. This previously happened to a different user, with a different error message, but went back to normal soon.

The user cannot delete any files in her My Documents folder. There are several files on network drives, but they are not affected. This is basically files in the users My Documents folder, the rest of the C:\ drive is not affected either. When the user tries to delete the file, a message pops up saying "You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from DOMAIN\CURRENTUSER to make changes to this file" where DOMAIN\CURRENTUSER is our domain and the user herself. However, I know that it is not a problem with the file, because the user can delete the files permanently using shift-delete, or from the command line. I also corrected it from the Recycle Bin properties by choosing "Don't move files to the recycle bin." The problem is not the recycle bin being too full, as it is empty, the file in question is a new blank text document, and the space allocated is 2047 MB.

I would really appreciate some insight to help find the cause of the problem. Until it can be fixed, I have it set to always permanently delete, which is an acceptable workaround for now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: duplicate the domain user.  See if the problem exists with that user.

Comment: Turns out that restarting the server got rid of the problem. The user can send files to the recycle bin again. Of course, if anyone can find the proper way to fix this, that would probably be helpful still.